# My Dropdown menu button drops down when I click but does pull back up when I click it again

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, toggle

My Dropdown menu button drops down when I click but does pull back up when I click it again. Is it a problem with the attributes? Bootstrap? jQuery?

Toggle navigation

Comment: Code please or at least a fiddle

Comment: What you are describing is the default behavior for the Dropdown [Fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/a5wwbzr2/).